# Installing Ubuntu from Live Persistence USB

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, persistence

I am currently running Ubuntu on a live persistence USB and I was wondering if it was possible to install Ubuntu onto the hard drive as well as all the data on the persistence flash drive. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Create an installed system (the main alternative)

- Yes, it is possible to install Ubuntu onto the hard drive from a persistent live system, but there are a few things to take care of (different depending on the installer that you use). The following link should help you avoid some pitfalls.

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Installing_-_using_the_Install_icon_on_the_desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Installing_-_using_the_Install_icon_on_the_desktop)
- The data saved on a persistent live drive the will **not** be transferred during a standard installation, but you can copy the home directory from the persistent live drive to a separate 'home' partition for the installed system, and select 'something else' alias manual partitioning during the installation and it will work.

  - You will probably have to change the name (ubuntu) and numerical user ID (999) to the name you select in the installed system and user ID (1000), so it might be easier to make a standard installation and simply copy back data files from your backup (or directly from the original location on USB drive).
  - You have to reinstall the program packages that were installed into the persistent live system, and you have to re-do the global tweaks.

### Create a persistent live system

- An alternative is to install a persistent live system into the internal drive or a USB-connected SSD. If you are using the same iso file (as you used for the USB pendrive), you can backup the content of the partition for persistence and restore it into the persistent live system into the internal drive or a USb-connected SSD, and it will contain 'everything' from the original system.
- Another alternative is to install a persistent live system into the internal drive or a USB-connected SSD and use a new (up to date) iso file. Then you can backup the content of the home directory of the original system and restore it to the new system (but you have to reinstall the program packages that were installed into the persistent live system, and you have to re-do the global tweaks.
- See the following link about backup and restore,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data)

Answer (score 3):

### Copy Data from Persistent USB to Hard Drive

In order to preserve permissions etc, it is preferable to use rsync to copy the data from the Persistent drives home folder to the new internal drive,

I prefer the GUI version called Grsync, it is available from Ubuntu Software.

Everything saved on a persistent USB is located in the persistent casper-rw file or partition, including the home folder.

**Grsync casper-rw File**

[image: Grsync casper-rw File]

To access a casper-rw file, make a directory:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper
```

and then mount casper-rw on it:

```
sudo mount -o loop /path/casper-rw /media/casper/
```

Where /path/ is the path to casper-rw file.

Path to file ~ /media/cscameron/xxx-xxx-xxx/casper-rw

**Grsync casper-rw Partition**

[image: Grsync casper-rw Partition]

The casper-rw partition can be accessed like any other partition.

Path to partition ~  /media/cscameron/casper-rw

Any programs that have been installed will need to be reinstalled but program data might exist in /casper-rw/upper/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the LiveUSB with Persistence can be used to install Ubuntu onto the internal drive. After completing the install and rebooting, you can copy from the Persistent LiveUSB to the internal drive.