# Please sir suggest me partition size of 1 tb HDD. Eg how much efi swap area home directory etc

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, boot-partition

Sir please suggest me how.much of memory from 1 TB. I can set for EFI swap area home directory boot physical or logical memory etc. Please sir give me full details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know the proper amount of needed disk space for EFI partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313154/how-to-know-the-proper-amount-of-needed-disk-space-for-efi-partition)

Comment: @Duplicate Post Police: This question has been asked many times on Ask Ubuntu, about a quarter of the times it has been closed as duplicate. This is the first time I see it being closed as opinion-based. How is the OP suppose to know how to partition his Ubuntu hard drive if no one will tell him? Obviously the answer changes over time as swapfiles are fairly new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition Size for 1 TB

1. 500MB - EFI
2. 200GB - /
3. 780GB - /home
4. 16GB - SWAP (keep double the memory of RAM for SWAP)

for '/' and '/home' size can be varied based on requirement.

Comment: 200GB for `/` when `/home/` is on a separate partition, is extremely generous...

Comment: Physical or logical .... And ex4 or anything else.... And i want to have 300gb as a single drive... Please help me bro

Comment: Sir. I am new to this

Comment: Please tell me which to be physical logical and which type eg ex4t etc

Comment: @Majid I believe if you use GPT (and from the presence of the EFI partition I deduct that you do) then all these can be physical partitions. (MBR limits the number of physical partitions, GPT less so.) The EFI partition will be FAT32 (but the installer will help with that one). `/` and `/home/` can be ext4, and the swap partition will not need such formatting; when you select a partition for swap, the installer takes care of it automatically.

Comment: Be sure to set drive to gpt (not old MBR(msdos). You have to do that before starting partitioning if partitioning in advance. You can also use gparted but must change default partitioning first.
Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu Partition Sizes

Ubuntu 18.04 and newer create a **swapfile** by themselves, a swap partition is not needed.

It is most efficient to keep home as part of the root, (/), partition. If separate, and one fills before the other, it becomes necessary modify partition sizes.

You can make the EFI partition the first on the disk with a size of 500MB.

You can use the remainder of the Disk for /.

You will want to backup your home directory on a separate disk for safe keeping and for possible reuse when you upgrade.

If Microsoft Windows is involved in the setup, via dual boot or Windows-To-Go USB, etc, you might want to allow some space, (100 to 800 GB), for a NTFS data partition that can be shared between Ubuntu and Windows, (as suggested by Archisman Panigrahi).

Comment: (I don't want to hijack your answer, that's why I did not edit), Would not it be a good idea to create a separate partition for data and not use the reminder of the disk for /, in case there is some unexpected major issue, and OP needs to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi I always make a separate NTFS data partition when installing to an external drive because there is a chance of using it for data on a Windows computer. A NTFS partition is not a stable as ext and I would only need it on my internal drive when using my Win-to-Go** USB drive on the computer.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi, Rereading your comment I see you are referring to a /home partition as a data partition. I have had as much success moving the home directory to a new clean install using Grsync as reusing the old /home partition. If you have just a / partition you can fill the whole drive without juggling partition sizes. I used a /home partition for years and finally found it inefficient.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229357/installing-ubuntu-from-live-persistence-usb

Comment: No, I was referring to a separate data partition. I use a separate NTFS data partition in my internal drive (in case I need to boot to Windows), a 30 GB home, and a 70 gb /. A separate /home never caused any issue in the last 3 years, but I don't keep important data in it, just in case I ever mess up the configuration files, and need to format /home during a reinstall.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi, Your suggestion added as an edit.